# Why this handler is not restricted to CTRL+L?

Tags: javascript, xbl

I have a XBL handler with the following signature:

```
<handler event="keypress" modifiers="control" keycode="DOM_VK_L">
```

As you see, it should be fired when the user press `CTRL+L`. But, for some reason, it fires when the user press CTRL+.

Why? And how to make it work exclusively for `CTRL+L`?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such attribute as **keycode** in [current standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/xbl/#key-event).
If you meant some implementation, which do not follow the standard, then you should mention it in question text.

And if you speak about Mozilla XBL1.0, then you need to use one from followings:

```
<handler event="keyup" modifiers="control" keycode="DOM_VK_L">
<handler event="keypress" modifiers="control" charcode="108">
```

108 is a ascii code for small L.

Comment: It's the Mozilla XBL, using `keyup` or `charcode="108"` it just doesn't fire the event.

Comment: try keypress with charcode="DOM_VK_SEPARATOR"(https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Event/UIEvent/KeyEvent

Comment: Nothing, I tried ctrl+l ctrl+L ctrl+space and others, but there was no even fired.

Comment: <handler event="keypress" key="l" modifiers="control" ... > https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/xultu/examples/ex_xblevents_1.xml.txt

Comment: something goes wrong when using a browser. But not in this sample. I need to do some tests here.. I'll back to post an update..